# Random sequence and random position?

Tags: python, numpy, random, sequence

I know how to generate random sequence of list of numbers. Here is an example :

```
lst = np.arange(10) #lst always 0 .. n
np.shuffle(lst)
```

the question is how to shuffle the numbers so that the number ONE is NOT at position ONE, 2 is not at pos 2, and in general x is not at position x. For all 0 .. n.

The initial sequence is always 0 .. n, where n will be in hundreds, 100 or 200 or 300.

---

looked at the thread... the shuffle methods seem unusable, too slow.
This is my current experiment, so far seems to work :

```
def swap(ary,pos):
  new_pos = np.random.randint(pos+1, len(ary))
  tmp = ary[pos]
  ary[pos] = ary[new_pos]
  ary[new_pos] = tmp
  #print "%s <=> %s" % (pos, new_pos)

def derange(n):
  lst = np.arange(n)
  for i in np.arange(n-1) : swap(lst, i)
  return lst
```

Comment: Shuffle and check, repeat. If that's not a solution you need to define your environment more as what's important and what's not (performance, bias).

Comment: What is the purpose?  An obvious answer would be to use np.arange(10,20) then shuffle.  So why is position and the value key to your problem.